# DataTable not binding to GridView after using ImportRow

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I am trying to create a summary GridView (GridView1) based on the % difference in values from the main gridview (GridView). It seems to be creating the summary data table fine but when I bind it to the grid view it doesn't do anything. I am not sure why?

```
    DataTable datatable = getDataTable(sqlSelect, sqlFilterBy);
    DataTable summaryTable = new DataTable();
    if (datatable.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView.DataSource = datatable;
        GridView.DataBind();
        gridView_Container.Visible = true;
        lblTableTitle.Text = "Run Information";
        lblTableTitle.Visible = true;

        IEnumerable<DataRow> runsQuery =
            from run in datatable.AsEnumerable()
            select run;

        IEnumerable<DataRow> overRuns =
            runsQuery.Where(p => p.Field<int>("% Difference") > 0);

        foreach (DataRow row in overRuns)
        {
            summaryTable.ImportRow(row);  
        }

        lblMessage.Text = summaryTable.Rows.Count.ToString();
        GridView1.DataSource = summaryTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

I know the problem occurs in the foreach loop where I import the row into the new summaryTable. A count of the number of the rows in the summaryTable returns the correct value. So I am certain they are in there. When I try to bind the GridView1 to rows found in the original datatable (used for GridView) this binds and displays the gridview also. So both parts are working independently (I think), but something is happening which isn't letting me bind the summaryTable to the grid view?

Sorry if my explanation isn't clear but I'm not entirely sure of what is wrong. This is my first time playing with dynamic querying so it's very possible I've done something obvious but wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is because your target  has no schema. I suggest clone the original `DataTable` to create the same schema(DataColumns etc).

```
summaryTable = runsQuery.Clone(); // copy schema.
foreach (DataRow row in overRuns)
{
     summaryTable.ImportRow(row);  
}
```

if you are using **.Net 3.5** or greater, you could use `CopyToDataTable` extension.

```
DataTable summaryTable = overRuns.CopyToDataTable();
```